# removeEventListener with Unique Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript, function, unique, dom-events, anonymous-function

I have an object that generates HTML elements that are also connected with an array of the object, and let us say we have one instance of it. So as it creates the elements it also assigns the following event listener to a nested part of the element (the class being uploadDelete).

Now this event listener needs to call the delete method of the instance of the object that created it, with the value of i assigned at its creation. Because events are under Window, the instance needed to be passed to an anonymous function along with the i value.

This therefore assigns a very unique function to the event, and because the delete method will be destroying the element containing the listener I would like to remove it first; from what I've read it could cause leaks otherwise(?). I'm also using Strict Mode, so not arguments.callee.

```
file.display.getElementsByClassName('uploadDelete')[0].addEventListener('click',
(function(that,i){
    return function() {
        that.delete(i);
    };
})(this,i), false);
```

I've tried many different things, but when I started having an anonymous function inside of a function inside of a function which is then called in the listener, I figured I should just ask on here. I might have a solution to the overall problem, changing other code, but it would still help if this could be answered.

---

Here is what I ended up doing, with the help of Norguard's answer. Since the uniqueness was stemming from an object called file, I just created a new property of file to store the function:

```
file.deleteFunction = (function(that,i){
    return function() {
        that.delete(i);
    };
})(this,i);

file.display.getElementsByClassName('uploadDelete')[0].addEventListener('click',file.deleteFunction, false);
```

The delete function that is called then removes the event listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relatively-painless way of doing this might be to create an object in the scope that's responsible for adding and deleting listeners, which builds an ID, serial or non, and will store whatever the listener is in an object, with that ID, returning the ID to whichever object/module requested it (or passing the anonymous function back to them).

```
// trivial example
var listeners = {},
    i = 0,


add = function (context, func, closure) {
    var enclosed = (function (closure) {
        return function () { /* ... */; func(); };
    }(closure)),
    index = i;

    context.addEventListener("...", enclosed, false);
    listeners[index] = enclosed;
    i += 1;
    return index;
};
```

`add` will now add your listener, but will also store the function that you're passing into addEventListener into the `listeners` object.
If you need a reference to `i`, you've already got it in the closure, if you want it.

So now when you remove stuff, you can just look for the function saved at `listeners[i]`.

An alternate, if you don't want to save a table full of these in one spot, for whatever reason, would be to catch the return statement, and instead of returning `i`, return the function;

```
// inside of your module
// I'm not usually crazy about `this`, without doing something particular with it,
// but hopefully it illustrates my point
this.cached_func = add(this.el, this.callback.bind(this), this.secret);
```

So now, when it comes time to delete everything, and you want to shut down your listener...

```
remove(this.cached_func);
```

All of that said, the leaks that you've read about are still possible, but the major culprit was IE6/7 (and earlier).
As people steer further from bad browsers, this becomes less important.
In fact, encouraging memory-dumps in IE6 is probably just a good way to encourage people to not use IE6.

Comment: This was similar to what I was beginning to think about doing. Thanks for the answer, and for clearing those things up!